# array.first does not seem to give me the first element from the array when called inside a map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

For some reason, `first` does not seem to give me the first element from the array when called inside a `map` block. Instead it returns me the first character of the `each` element in an array.
So basically:

```
@phones.map { |phone| phone.employee.number }
```

Returns:

```
["123-456-7890", "123-456-7890"]
```

But:

```
@phones.map { |phone| phone.employee.number.first }
```

Returns:

```
["1", "1"]
```

In my console `array.first` seems to work fine:

```
a = ["123-456-7890", "123-456-7890"]
=> [
  [0] "123-456-7890",
  [1] "123-456-7890"
]
 »  a.first
=> "123-456-7890"
```

Can someone see what's wrong above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to grab a single phone number, you would call `first` on the block, not on the number:

```
@phones.map { |phone| phone.employee.number }.first
```

However, assuming all phones have an employee, and all employees have a number, you could just do:

```
@phones.first.employee.number
```

Comment: *not on the number*, No, that's a `String`. Not any number.. :) `"123-456-7890"` a string.. not a number..

Comment: @ArupRakshit I didn't mean "number" as in Integer, I meant as in "phone number"

Comment: @DylanMarkow Yeah!! Its Ok.. :)

Answer (score 1):

`phone.employee.number` gives you `String` instance. As as per the rails [`String#first`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-first) it would give the first character. Thus `phone.employee.number.first` gives you `1` from each strings `"123-456-7890"` and `"123-456-7890"`. So you got `["1", "1"]`.

Use `@phones.map { |phone| phone.employee.number }.first`. Now this is a call to [`Array#first`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-first), not a `String#first`. Now it will give you `"123-456-7890"`.

Comment: sorry, but the answer you provided looks like the same stuff I tried and posted in my question above

Comment: @Micheal That was a typo.. Sorry.. :)

Comment: @Micheal except that Arup's explanation is better :P

Comment: @Abdo I copied code, then forgot to make that changes to be done :) As my boss was calling me :)